# Rest Api fetching only one random post

Tags: rest-api

My blog link is given below

https://docs.gocharting.com

My attempt to fetch posts or all posts by categories etc. is fetching the same result which is a single random post. I am not sure why.

I have tried below calls

1. [https://docs.gocharting.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[cat]=28](https://docs.gocharting.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter%5Bcat%5D=28)
2. https://docs.gocharting.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&page=1

Comment: Please show the code you are using to fetch.

Comment: I tried the below  1.  https://docs.gocharting.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=100&page=1  and 2. https://docs.gocharting.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?filter[cat]=28

Comment: Do you definitely have more than one post, of type = post? That's all we can see over the API. Do you have custom post types set up, and is everything a different type? Do you have plugins that e.g. filter what unauthenticated users can see, that might also be filtering this list? But from the API it looks like you only have one post and one page, yes.